# Backing up to S3: symlinks

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, s3cmd

I'm trying to figure out right now how to backup some data to S3.

We have a local backup system implemented using rsnapshot and that works perfectly.  We're trying to use s3cmd with the --sync option to mimic rsync to transfer the files.

The problem we're having is that symlinks aren't created as symlinks, it seems to be resolving them to the physical file and uploading that instead.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this would happen?

Am I missing something obvious? Or is it that S3 just isn't suited to this sort of operation? I could setup an EC2 instance and attach some EBS, but it'd be preferable to use S3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no symlinks available on S3 but what you can use is google's solution which creates a based file system using S3 (FUSE) . More information here :

https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon

and here:

http://tjstein.com/articles/mounting-s3-buckets-using-fuse/

I hope it helps

Comment: You can mount an S3 bucket use S3FS but it still cannot handle symlinks. If you copy a symlink to an S3FS mount, it simply copies the symlink destination file, not the symlink itself.

Answer (score 9):

Amazon S3 itself doesn't have the concept of symlinks, which is why I suspect s3cmd uploads the physical file. Its a limitation of S3, not s3cmd.

I'm assuming that you need the symlink itself copied though? If that's the case, can you gzip/tar your directory with symlink and upload that?

Comment: Closest to answering the question with an actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `-F, --follow-symlinks` OPTiON when using `sync`. This worked for me.

Comment: for everyone who is searching for "howto backup files to s3 and follow symlinks", this is correct, you have to use the param `-F`

Comment: Sadly, that is exactly what OP *didn't* want. So this is a bad answer to the question.